# Are questions about learning to type in an L2 on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, scope

I am currently learning a language whose standard typing layout is very different to that of my native language. At some point I am going to want to learn to touch-type it, and I suspect that learning typing will actually build my spelling ability in the language.

Are questions about how to learn to type an L2 on a keyboard or similar device on-topic?

Comment: Hmm… what makes you doubt? Typing seems to be an integral part of language acquisition, along with speaking, reading, and writing.

Comment: @bytebuster I can envision some people seeing it as as a computer usage question rather than a language learning question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would accept such questions. Since learning to write in a foreign language can be on topic, so can learning to type. I am assuming that such questions would not be solely about where to find an input method for an L2.
(There may be a fine line here, since we previously had a question about [IME for Russian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/541/800).)

Comment: If you're calling into question whether asking about finding an input method for a language would be on-topic, my opinion is that it would be ok. Admittedly, we do have a [software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, but their [selection of IME questions is fairly sparse](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=ime) (6 results at time of posting).